# Intersection of subsets of additive groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Given two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a finite additive group $Z$, how
can one show that there exists an element $x$ in $Z$ such that
$$1 - \frac{|A \cap (B + x)|}{|Z|} \le \left(1 - \frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left(1 - \frac{|B|}{|Z|} \right).$$
(This is part of exercise 1.1.4 of Tao and Vu's *Additive Combinatorics* book).

Any idea how the stated inequality could be proved?
The left-hand side seems to be the probability of an element of $Z$ not belonging to
$A \cap (B + x)$ and the right-hand side the probability of selecting
an element $a$ from $Z \backslash A$ and an element $b$ from $Z \backslash B$.

It seems possible to show that $E(|A \cap (B + x)|)$ among
elements $x$ in $Z$ is $|A||B| / |Z|$:
for each pair $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, there is exactly one element
$z$ in $Z$ such that $a = b + z$; thus there are $|A||B|$ such triples.
Averaging this for the elements of $Z$, we obtain the
desired expectation.  The first moment method implies an element $x$ in $Z$ such that
$$1 - \frac{|A \cap (B + x)|}{|Z|} \le 1 - \frac{|A||B|}{|Z|^2},$$
which seems weaker than the bound stated in the problem.

Comment: In fact, in this exercise, $A\cap(B+x)$ should be $A\cup(B+x)$. You can find the errata of the book in Terry Tao's blog.